# Sendkeys to VSCode with Powershell: only works 1st time, 2nd time, why do I get an error about nodejs?

Tags: node.js, powershell, winapi, visual-studio-code, electron

When I paste this in Powershell Console, it works

```
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
$wshell.AppActivate('Untitled-1')
Sleep 1
$wshell.SendKeys('Hello World 1~')
Sleep 1
$wshell.SendKeys('Hello World 2~')
```

But if I paste second time, I have a weird message about nodejs whereas It has nothing to do with what I'm doing ?!

Update: I suspect Electronjs so I add it in tag :)

[image]

Comment: You should always release com objects after use. Not sure if that causes the error, but end your code with `[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($wshell) | Out-Null; [System.GC]::Collect(); [System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()`

Comment: @Theo thanks for this code, I'll use it I prefer clean code. Though no I tried it doesn't come from that, it really does come from VSCode ElectronJs.